# What angle should the XY plane rotate?

Tags: geometry

[image]

What angle do I need to rotate the XY plane to make the lines with an angle of 45° from the X axis appear to be at an angle of 22.5° from the X axis? How do I calculate it?

Comment: Well, you cannot have both cases you depict in your question with a rotation. Say the right line rotates anti clockwise, then the other line *also* will rotate anti clockwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required vertical scale factor is $\tan22.5°=\sqrt2-1$. This factor is the cosine of the rotation angle, $\arccos(\sqrt2-1)\approx65.5302°.$

Answer (score 0):

Check the following matrix does the trick

$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos 22.5^\circ&-\sin22.5^\circ\\
\sin22.5^\circ&\;\;\cos22.5^\circ\end{pmatrix}$$